# Question about union with $\{∅\}$: $\{1,2\}\cup \{∅\}=\{1,2,∅\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**I have two quick questions:

a.**
$\{1,2\}\cup \{∅\}=\{1,2,∅\}$ 
is it correct ?

**b.**
can I have an explanation why is it not just $\{1,2\}$? Or more importantly why is it important to mention the $∅$ if it is empty? After all $\{1,2\}\cup ∅=\{1,2\}$.
It is a bit unclear to me.Thank you.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: 1) Yes it's correct.  2) Because $\emptyset$ is something.  You can't ignore it.  It is not nothing.   3) After all {1,2}$\cup \emptyset = \{1,2\}$.  $\{\emptyset\} \ne \emptyset$.  $\{\emptyset\}$ is a set that has one thing in it.  It has the empty set in it?  See it?  It's right there.  $\emptyset$ is a set that has nothing in it.  Nothing at all.  A set itself, and the contents inside a set, are different things and should not be confused.  {1,2} $\ne$ either the number one or two.  {{1,2}} $\ne$ {1,2} etc.  Nothing is nothing.  As set with nothing in it is not nothing; it's a set.

Answer (score 6):

$\varnothing = \{\}$

It is the empty set.   It is not just nothing.   It is a set with no elements.

Sets can be elements of other sets.   The set of the emepty set is not empty, it contains the empty set.   $\{\varnothing\}=\{\{\}\}$

So we have that:
$\{1,2\}\cup\{\} = \{1,2\}$ but $\{1,2\}\cup\{{\small\{\}}\} = \{1,2,{\small\{\}}\}$

Similar to:
$\{1,2\}\cup\{3\} = \{1,2,3\}$ but $\{1,2\}\cup\{{\small\{3\}}\} = \{1,2,{\small\{3\}}\}$

Answer (score 2):

$\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are two different things. The first one is the empty set, while the second is a singleton, i.e. a set having a single element, namely the empty set.

Similarly, $\{1,2,\emptyset\}$ has three elements, among which the empty set, while $\{1,2\}$ only has two.

So at the same time, $\emptyset\subset\{1,2,\emptyset\}$ and $\emptyset\in\{1,2,\emptyset\}$.

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}$ can also be expressed as $\{\{\}\}$, which makes it easier to distinguish from $\emptyset$ or $\{\}$.

Answer (score 1):

a) It is correct.

b) $\{1,2\}\cup\varnothing=\{1,2\}$. This because $\varnothing$ is empty, i.e. it has no elements. However $\{\varnothing\}$ is *not* empty. It contains an element, and this element is $\varnothing$.

Union $\{1,2\}\cup\{\varnothing\}$ is the set containing exactly the elements of $\{1,2\}$, i.e. $1$ and $2$, *and* the elements of $\{\varnothing\}$, i.e. $\varnothing$.

Likewise union $\{1,2\}\cup\varnothing$ is the set containing exactly the elements of $\{1,2\}$, i.e. $1$ and $2$, *and* the elements of $\varnothing$, i.e. no elements at all.